# Vue3 specify thumbnail image in meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, meta-tags

In a Vue 3 project, I am trying to implement an [image thumbnail](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/1626955?hl=en) in the head section.

I have tried different ways:

```
<meta name="thumbnail" content="<%= BASE_URL %>assets/images/image.webp" />
```

and

```
<meta name="thumbnail" content="@/assets/images/image.webp" />
```

When I view the page code after building, that same image when referenced in a Vue component in an `<img>` tag looks like `my-base-url/img/image.74adcb8b.webp`.

But the link in the head section looks like `content="/my-base-url/assets/images/image.webp"` or like `content="@/assets/images/image.webp"` which are both invalid URLs.

If I try to open these URLs, I get

> `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/my-base-url/assets/images/image.webp"`

I have also tried dynamically injecting the element in the head section from my component:

```
beforeCreate() {

  // Add thumbnail image to head section
  let thumb = document.createElement('META')
  thumb.setAttribute('name', 'thumbnail')
  thumb.setAttribute('content', '@/assets/images/image.webp')

  document.querySelector(`head`).appendChild(thumb)
}
```

But the outcome is exaclty the same.

**How am I supposed to create a valid link to an image in the head section?**

Comment: give a minimally reproducible example this is a compiler problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use public directory and

```
<meta name="thumbnail" content="/image.webp" />
```

that's it

[more](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html)

Comment: Does this go in `index.html`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir This answer focuses on importing assets from the public folder.